# Trouble installing foreign key in child records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

Problem is that Rails can't find the new route after i changed how the routes for indis (stands for individuals or 'contacts') are generated.

in my routes file as a result of this statement

resources :profiles do
    resources :indis
  end

these routes were generated among others:

profile_indis

```
          GET    /profiles/:profile_id/indis(.:format)   indis#index

          POST   /profiles/:profile_id/indis(.:format)   indis#create
```

profile is the company and indis are individuals that work at the company

so i'm sitting here looking at this which is new.html.erb for new contacts.

```
  <h1>New Contact</h1>

  <%= render 'form', indi: @indi %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
```

I have the following line at the top of routes to avoid the rails router using the basic create route.
  resources :indis, :except => [:create]
in routes

i get
No route matches [POST] "/indis"

hint:  i added the :except code because the old route wasn't valid after i made the change 
  resources :profiles do
    resources :indis
  end

now when i hit create it can't find the route and i don't know what code 
<%= render 'form', indi: @indi %> generates

somehow i need to fixup the new contact code so that when they hit create it routes to the new route instead of the old one (but I don't have access to the code of the form referenced in the new contact code.

Comment: the result of all this is that i can't access the foreign key in the indis controller because the create new record doesn't know to pass all the parameters to the controller, specifically it does not pass the foreign key.

Comment: starting to think render 'form' refers to a partial .  i am new to rails.

Comment: here's what top of _form.html.erb looks like                                                                                            <%= form_with(model: indi, local: true) do |form| %>                                                                               but now that indi is dependent on parent i think this code doesn't know the parents key and thus can't pass in foreign key.

Comment: i think what happened is that after running the scaffold i changed the model to add a foreign key but i never updated the view so the views don't contain the new foreign key field

Comment: <%= form_for(@indi, url: {controller: "indis", action: "create"}, method: "post") do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.hidden_field :profile_id, {  :value => params[:profile_id]} %>
  </div>   solved the problem..  i got rid of the partial so I could better understand what I had to do.

Comment: what i ended up doing is passing foreign key via a hidden field so that the value posts correctly.